# How many character can a STL string class can hold?

Tags: c++, string, stl

I need to work with a series of characters. The number of characters can be upto 10<sup>11</sup>.
In a usual array, it's not possible. What should I use? 
I wanted to use gets() function to hold the string. But, is this possible for STL containers?
If not, then what's the way?

Example:
input:
AMIRAHID
output: A.M.I.R.A.H.I.D

How to make this possible if the number of characters lessened to 10^10 in 32-bit machine ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's way too much data for an affordable machine's RAM (and nothing, not even STL can pack 100 characters into one byte). There's no way you need all this data at the same time. Break it into smaller much chunks.

Comment: "Standar Library" != "STL", and `std::string` isn't from that part of the std lib that stems from the STL.

Comment: @sbi: Errr.. it isn't? Because `std::string` is definitely an STL container.

Comment: @Billy: An STL interface was retro-fitted to the much older `std::basic_string` when the STL was incorporated into the std lib. But it definitely wasn't part of the original STL.

Comment: @Rahi: Can you explain what operations require all the data to be held in memory? Your example input/output certainly doesn't require it.

Comment: @Rahi: what is this data? How come you can just reduce it from 10^11 to 10^10 characters just like that? And didn't you read the answers you got, which would have told you that the exact same problem applies to 10^10 characters. It's still more than you can fit in memory on a 32bit machine. What is this for? Even if you snap your finger again and magically reduce the data so much that it'll fit, what you're doing is still going to be ridiculously slow and inefficient. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 6):

Well, that's roughly 100GByte of data. No usual string class will be able to hold more than fits into your main memory. You might want to look at [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/), which is an implementation of STL allowing to store part of the data on disk.

Comment: Well, not main memory -- virtual memory is allowed to use the disk too!

Answer (score 3):

If your machine has 10<sup>11</sup> == 93GB of memory then it's probably a 64bit machine, so `string` will work. Otherwise nothing will help you.

**Edited answer for the edited question:** In that case you don't really need to store the whole string in memory. You can store only small part of it that fits into the memory.

Just read every character from the input, write it to the output and write a dot after it. Repeat it until you get and EOF on the input. To increase performance you can read and write large chunks of the data but such that still can fit into the memory.

Such algorithms are called *online algorithms*.

Comment: std::string is not the correct type for things like this. It may technically work but its not designed for this usage and thus would be very in-efficient. C++ program is about picking the correct type for your data so sorry -1

Comment: @Martin: well, the answer is still correct. The OP didn't ask what a sane way to handle this amount of data was, just what the limit was on `std::string`.

Comment: @jalf: Sorry my mistake. Always assumed people would want a sane maintainable solution. :-p But other wise yes ;-)

Comment: @Martin: in my experience, it's very unwise to make assumptions about the sanity of others ;)

Answer (score 2):

It *is* possible for an array that large to be created. But not on a 32-bit machine. Switching to STL will likely not help, and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to contemplate how much memory that is, and if you have any chance of doing it at all.

10<sup>11</sup> is roughly 100 gigabytes, which means you will need a 64-bit system (and compiler) to even be able to address it.

STL's strings support a max of `max_size()` characters, so the answer can change with the implementation.

Comment: Isn't the value of `max_size()` defined or at least limited by the standard ?

Comment: Input: AMIRAHID Output:A.M.I.R.A.H.I.D  , if the number of characters is nearly upto 10^10, how to do this possible in a 32 bit machine?

Comment: @Rahi: Read single character. Print character. Print dot. Repeat.

Comment: @ereOn: From docs on `std::allocator`: `Returns: a.max_size() if that expression is well-formed; otherwise, numeric_limits<size_type>::max().` . From Docs on string: `Returns: the largest value N for which the call allocate(N,0) might succeed.`

Answer (score 1):

A string suffers from the same problem as an array: **it has to fit in memory*.

10^11 characters would take up over 4GB. That's hard to fit into memory on a 32-bit machine which has a 4GB memory space. You either need to split up your data into smaller chunks, and only load a bit of it at a time, or switch to 64-bit, in which case *both* arrays and strings should be able to hold the data (although it may still be preferable to split it up into multiple smaller strings/arrays

Comment: Well, strictly speaking a 32 bit machine can use more than 4GB of memory, but not by a single process in a single continuous array (For example, processors with "Physical Address Extension" turned on). The 4GB limit is only per virtual memory space.

Comment: @Billy: but both strings and arrays are required to be contiguous (and *in general*, a 32-bit machine is defined by having a 32-bit memory space. Individual architectures may have tricks to work around this, but that's not the same as saying that an arbitrary 32-bit machine can use more than 4GB. ;)

Comment: Well, assuming we're talking about virtual memory systems, that's not being overly specific at all. In any case, my point is not that it would make sense for a single string to be more than 2GB on a single system, merely that that system can in fact address more than 4GB of physical RAM, because "32 bit" refers to a single process' virtual address space, and if you have multiple processes they could in fact consume more than 4GB of physical RAM.

Answer (score 1):

The SGI version of STL has a ROPE class (A rope is a big string, get it).

I am not sure it is designed to handle that much data but you can have a look.
http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is read in some massive file and write to another file the same data with periods interspersed between each character, why bother reading the whole thing into memory at once? Pick some reasonable buffer size and do it in chunks.